# How can we increase the speed of single task execution in GAE Task Queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a single large task that is running in one of the task queues. Sometimes the task takes more than 24 hours to execute. I have optimized my code to the maximum and have achieved some speed to execute the task faster.

The task performs the operation of inserting the rows into the datastore which can be in millions.

Is there any way to increase the speed of that task by allocating more resources or by making changes in the instance configurations?

Please advise.

Comment: refactor it to run multiple tasks concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get *some* speedup by choosing an [instance type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes) with a faster CPU (also more expensive) in the respective service/module config file.

But the percent reduction of the overall task duration depends significantly on the actual structure/operation of your app.

You'll get a speedup for what is actually executed by your instance (i.e. your app code), but not for the services executed by the GAE infra, like datastore and memcache RPCs for example - which can be significant.